# Converting Youtube Data API V3 video duration format to standard time in PHP

Tags: php, youtube-data-api

I'm, getting this array from a youtube API request, but the duration format is very rare in my opinion. Why didn't they just throw seconds in there? In any case this is the array

```
[duration] => PT2M3S
[dimension] => 2d
[definition] => sd
[caption] => false
```

Is there a way to convert this duration to a "H:i:s" format in PHP?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact it is simple ISO8601 date. Split string with regexp like `(\d+)` to minutes and seconds. Then get integer part of division of minutes by 60 to get hours. Get remainder of that division to get minutes.

here is an example that should work though i didn't tested it

```
preg_match_all('/(\d+)/',$youtube_time,$parts);

$hours = floor($parts[0][0]/60);
$minutes = $parts[0][0]%60;
$seconds = $parts[0][1];
```

Comment: Thanks for the approach, at the end I did this.

`code`
    $duration = new DateInterval($videoData['duration']);

    $videoDuration = (60 * 60 * $duration->h) + (60 *  $duration->i)     + $duration->s;
    
    print gmdate("H:i:s",  $videoDuration);

Comment: this will get wrong data if you have schema like that : PT54S , youtube will give you this duration if video less than 1 minute

Answer (score 7):

acidjazz has a great solution, but there is a typo where it displays the minutes. It should be `$di->i` for minutes, not `$di->m`. You can also remove the "public static" portion if you're not using it in an object, and I took out the `sprintf()`.

Otherwise the function works as is:

```
function duration($ytDuration) {

    $di = new DateInterval($ytDuration);
    $string = '';

    if ($di->h > 0) {
      $string .= $di->h.':';
    }

    return $string.$di->i.':'.$di->s;
}
```

I would have added this as a comment to his answer, but there's the whole "You need 50 reputation to comment" BS that prevents me from sticking to the flow of this thread.

Comment: Yes, it's correctly result.
However, in my case. I always use sprintf('%02s', 'xx') in all hour, minute, second. (xx means those unit).
If no zero leading the result might be 1:2:6 for 1 hour 2 minutes 6 seconds. It looks strange for 1:2:6.

Thank you for this answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use php's [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php) Class to parse it properly. For example a function in a youtube wrapper class to parse it to the format YouTube displays might look like:

```
  public static function duration($ytDuration) {

    $di = new DateInterval($ytDuration);
    $string = '';

    if ($di->h > 0) {
      $string .= $di->h.':';
    }

    return $string.$di->m.':'.sprintf('%02s',$di->s);
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I used @chris-z-s 's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148885/converting-youtube-data-api-v3-video-duration-format-to-seconds-in-javascript-no#answer-25209563) ,  and converted it to php :

```
function getDurationSeconds($duration){
    preg_match_all('/[0-9]+[HMS]/',$duration,$matches);
    $duration=0;
    foreach($matches as $match){
        //echo '<br> ========= <br>';       
        //print_r($match);      
        foreach($match as $portion){        
            $unite=substr($portion,strlen($portion)-1);
            switch($unite){
                case 'H':{  
                    $duration +=    substr($portion,0,strlen($portion)-1)*60*60;            
                }break;             
                case 'M':{                  
                    $duration +=substr($portion,0,strlen($portion)-1)*60;           
                }break;             
                case 'S':{                  
                    $duration +=    substr($portion,0,strlen($portion)-1);          
                }break;
            }
        }
    //  echo '<br> duratrion : '.$duration;
    //echo '<br> ========= <br>';
    }
     return $duration;

}
```

it worked with me :)

Answer (score 1):

May be it will be helpful for someone to get duration:

```
$interval = new \DateInterval($iso8601);

// in seconds:
$seconds = $interval->h * 360 + $interval->i * 60 + $interval->s;

// in "H:i:s" format:
echo $interval->format('%H:%i:%s');
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution:

```
preg_match('/(\d+)H/', $duration, $match);
$h = ($match[0])?filter_var($match[0], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT).":":'';
preg_match('/(\d+)M/', $duration, $match);
$m = filter_var($match[0], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT).":";
preg_match('/(\d+)S/', $youtube_date, $match);
$s = filter_var($match[0], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
echo: "Duration: " . $h.$m.$s;
```

Answer (score 0):

##:##:## Time format on PHP

```
 function NormalizeDuration($duration){
    preg_match('#PT(.*?)H(.*?)M(.*?)S#si',$duration,$out);
    if(empty($out[1])){
    preg_match('#PT(.*?)M(.*?)S#si',$duration,$out);
    if(empty($out[1])){
    preg_match('#PT(.*?)S#si',$duration,$out);
    if(empty($out[1])){
    return '00:00';
    }
    }else{
    if(strlen($out[1])==1){ $out[1]= '0'.$out[1]; }
    if(strlen($out[2])==1){ $out[2]= '0'.$out[2]; }
    return $out[1].':'.$out[2];
    }
    }else{
    if(strlen($out[1])==1){ $out[1]= '0'.$out[1]; }
    if(strlen($out[2])==1){ $out[2]= '0'.$out[2]; }
    if(strlen($out[3])==1){ $out[3]= '0'.$out[3]; }
    return $out[1].':'.$out[2].':'.$out[3];
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following php function will return the YouTube video duration..For more exciting codes follow this [link](http://smarttips.in/category/youtube/) [more code samples](http://smarttips.in/category/youtube/)

```
    function getYoutubeDuration($vid) 
    {
    $videoDetails =file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=".$vid."&part=contentDetails&key=AIzaSyDen99uTRRPl9VT_Ra9eAisvZSc4aZDEns");
    $videoDetails =json_decode($videoDetails, true);
    foreach ($videoDetails['items'] as $vidTime)
     {
        $youtube_time = $vidTime['contentDetails']['duration'];
        preg_match_all('/(\d+)/',$youtube_time,$parts);
        $hours = (strlen(floor($parts[0][0]/60))<1)?floor($parts[0][0]/60):'0'.floor($parts[0][0]/60);
        $minutes = $parts[0][0]%60; (strlen($parts[0][0]%60)<1)?$parts[0][0]%60:'0'.$parts[0][0]%60;
        $seconds = $parts[0][1];(strlen($parts[0][1])<1)?$parts[0][1]:'0'.$parts[0][1];
        return $hours.":".$minutes.":".$seconds;
     }
    }

  echo getYoutubeDuration('J1lb3qJgfho');
```

Answer (score 0):

As YouTube (Google) like to be difficult, they opt for non-standard formatting.
So standard functions don't always work.

As such, I made this for my need's.

```
$length = $data['items'] ..... ['duration'];

$seconds = substr(stristr($length, 'S', true), -2, 2);
$seconds = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $seconds);
$minutes =  substr(stristr($length, 'M', true), -2, 2);
$minutes = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $minutes);
$hours =  substr(stristr($length, 'H', true), -2, 2);
$hours = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $hours);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with named groups

```
PT((?P<hours>\d+)H)?((?P<minutes>\d+)M)?((?P<seconds>\d+)S)?
```

Examples can be found here https://regex101.com/r/wU3hT2/114

Python function:

```py
def yt_time_to_seconds(time):
    regex_string = 'PT((?P<hours>\d+)H)?((?P<minutes>\d+)M)?((?P<seconds>\d+)S)?'
    regex = re.compile(regex_string)
    match = regex.match(time)
    if match:
        hours = int(match.group('hours'))
        minutes = int(match.group('minutes'))
        seconds = int(match.group('seconds'))
        return hours * 60 * 60 + minutes * 60 + seconds
    return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

it worked perfectly for me 100%, only you should have \ DateInterval as root

```
function NormalizeDuration($duration){ //pass your time
    $start = new \DateTime('@0');
    $start->add(new \DateInterval($duration));

    return $start->format('H:i:s'); //format
}
```