# Converting Youtube Data API V3 video duration format to seconds in Dart

Tags: regex, flutter, dart, duration

In my case i get the time in this format  : PT2H3M20S i have no idea about the regex expression [using dart] so I just want to know how can we calculate milliseconds from above format.. thanks in advance

```
  Future<http.Response> getVideoDuration({var videoUri}) async {
    // print(videoUri);
    final BI_YT_API_KEY = "some_API";
    var lArr = videoUri.split('/');
    var lId = lArr[lArr.length - 1];
    var data = await http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos' +
        "?id=$lId&part=contentDetails&key=$BI_YT_API_KEY");
    if (data.statusCode == 200) {
      var jom = json.decode(data.body);
      print(jom['items'][0]['contentDetails']['duration']);
      var duration = data.body[0];
    }
```

Comment: The above format doesn't show milliseconds. Can you show your actual code as to where you are trying to receive milliseconds ?

Comment: @NisanthReddy yes it doesn't show milliseconds, I just want to separate the hour,minute, and seconds and calculate it to get milliseconds that's it ... but the problem is I don't know how to get that hour, minute, and seconds separately for every test case

Comment: Where are you getting this format from ? You need to post code for us to be able to help.

Comment: Regex doesn’t “do” anything to the input, except match it. It certainly doesn’t do any kind of transformation whatsoever. To convert this format to milliseconds you’re going to need to write some code. At a glance I would expect regex to be of little to no help.

Comment: @NisanthReddy i have added the code

Comment: What time is `PT2H3M20S` supposed to represent?  Is it a timestamp or a duration?  Is it supposed to mean 2 hours, 3 minutes, 20 seconds?  If so, that's a duration, which should be stored a `Duration` object; a `DateTime` object would be inappropriate.

Comment: @SourabhBankar. This is what you are looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148885/converting-youtube-data-api-v3-video-duration-format-to-seconds-in-javascript-no. It is in Javascript. If you need it in Dart, ask.

Comment: @NisanthReddy yes perfect.. i need it in dart

Comment: Alright, will convert it and post.

Comment: @SourabhBankar. Fiiinally done. Check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Took some time. But fiinally done.

You can use it like this.

```
int seconds = convertTime("PT1H11S");
```

Here, `seconds` will be the converted duration in seconds. So, for `PT1H11S`, the answer will be, `3611` because of `1 hour == 3600 seconds` + `11 seconds`.

```
int convertTime(String duration) {

  RegExp regex = new RegExp(r'(\d+)');
  List<String> a = regex.allMatches(duration).map((e) => e.group(0)!).toList();

  if (duration.indexOf('M') >= 0 &&
      duration.indexOf('H') == -1 &&
      duration.indexOf('S') == -1) {
    a = ["0", a[0], "0"];
  }

  if (duration.indexOf('H') >= 0 && duration.indexOf('M') == -1) {
    a = [a[0], "0", a[1]];
  }
  if (duration.indexOf('H') >= 0 &&
      duration.indexOf('M') == -1 &&
      duration.indexOf('S') == -1) {
    a = [a[0], "0", "0"];
  }

  int seconds = 0;

  if (a.length == 3) {
    seconds = seconds + int.parse(a[0]) * 3600;
    seconds = seconds + int.parse(a[1]) * 60;
    seconds = seconds + int.parse(a[2]);
  }

  if (a.length == 2) {
    seconds = seconds + int.parse(a[0]) * 60;
    seconds = seconds + int.parse(a[1]);
  }

  if (a.length == 1) {
    seconds = seconds + int.parse(a[0]);
  }
  return seconds;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** I do not know flutter but I have heard that a flutter developer should be able to use Java code. This answer is based on Java.

## tl;dr

With Java, all you need is:

```
Duration.parse("PT2H3M20S").toMillis()
```

[`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) is modelled on [ISO-8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and was introduced with *Java-8* as part of [JSR-310 implementation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr310/JSR-310-guide.html).

If you have gone through the above links, you might have already noticed that `PT2H3M20S` specifies a duration of 2 hours 3 minutes 20 seconds that you can parse to a `Duration` object which you can convert into milliseconds.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Duration;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strIso8601Duration = "PT2H3M20S";
        Duration duration = Duration.parse(strIso8601Duration);
        long millis = duration.toMillis();
        System.out.println(millis);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
7400000
```

Learn more about the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I also managed to get the duration in seconds using dart (If in case someone needed it)

```
/// For duration  = 2H1M48S
converToSeconds(String duration){

      var hour = "", minute = "", seconds = "";
      var tempList = duration.split('');

      /// HOUR
      if (tempList.contains('H')) {
        var ind = tempList.indexOf('H');
        for (int i = 0; i < ind; i++) {
          hour = hour + tempList[i];
        }
        tempList.removeRange(0, ind + 1);
      }

      /// MINUTES
      if (tempList.contains('M')) {
        var ind = tempList.indexOf('M');
        for (int i = 0; i < ind; i++) {
          minute = minute + tempList[i];
        }
        tempList.removeRange(0, ind + 1);
      }

      /// SECONDS
      if (tempList.contains('S')) {
        var ind = tempList.indexOf('S');
        for (int i = 0; i < ind; i++) {
          seconds = seconds + tempList[i];
        }
        tempList.removeRange(0, ind + 1);
      }

      /// CONVER TO INT
      hour = hour != "" ? hour : '0';
      seconds = seconds != "" ? seconds : '0';
      minute = minute != "" ? minute : '0';

      var ms = ((int.parse(hour) * 3600 + int.parse(minute) * 60) + int.parse(seconds));
}
```

Comment: {Sigh.} Would have been so much clearer as a Regex.  Part of the reason most modern languages have regex.