# Converting Youtube Data API V3 video duration format to seconds in Python3

Tags: python, python-re

I wanna convert the Youtube Data API V3 video duration format to seconds in python.
ex:

```
PT1H
PT23M
PT45S
PT1H23M
PT1H45S
PT23M45S
PT1H23M45S
```

I think I need to use the re in python but I dont have enough experience in re.
If you provide the code to convert the duration format to seconds, it will be appreciated to me.
I am following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148885/converting-youtube-data-api-v3-video-duration-format-to-seconds-in-javascript-no)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code to achive what you have asked:

```py
import datetime

given_string = 'PT1H23M45S'
new_string = given_string.split('T')[1]

if 'H' in new_string and 'M' in new_string and 'S' in new_string:
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(new_string, '%HH%MM%SS')
    time_sec = int(dt.hour) * 3600 + int(dt.minute) * 60 + int(dt.second)

elif 'M' in new_string and 'S' in new_string:
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(new_string, '%MM%SS')
    time_sec = int(dt.minute) * 60 + int(dt.second)

elif 'H' in new_string and 'M' in new_string:
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(new_string, '%HH%MM')
    time_sec = int(dt.hour) * 3600 + int(dt.minute) * 60

elif 'H' in new_string and 'S' in new_string:
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(new_string, '%HH%SS')
    time_sec = int(dt.hour) * 3600 + int(dt.second)

elif 'H' in new_string:
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(new_string, '%HH')
    time_sec = int(dt.hour) * 3600

elif 'M' in new_string:
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(new_string, '%HH')
    time_sec = int(dt.hour) * 60

else:
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(new_string, '%SS')
    time_sec = int(dt.second)

print(time_sec)
```

Comment: thanks, The code works well for only 'PT1H23M45S', it does not work for other cases. I need the code for all cases. Please help me! thanks

Comment: Understood, I did not see that you might not have hours or minutes string in some of your cases. In that case you might need to setup the try and error blocks or if blocks. I am updating the code for the same. Have a look in sometime.

Comment: Modified the code as per your need. Have a look.

Comment: I will be appreciate to your update

Comment: I made some typo. Corrected. Check now!