# What is the time format PT1H38M24S?

Tags: php

This is my You tube url

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id=fS7w-TXinPE&key=AIzaSyC4lRjR4DGfL2l0VmBRvd1QcWr_lLlPIj0

It returns this response:

```
{
  kind: "youtube#videoListResponse",
  etag: ""sGDdEsjSJ_SnACpEvVQ6MtTzkrI/w7nxpQxTlGkdBoZPAIBIF2cALdw"",
  pageInfo: {
    totalResults: 1,
    resultsPerPage: 1
  },  
  items: [
    {
      kind: "youtube#video",
      etag: ""sGDdEsjSJ_SnACpEvVQ6MtTzkrI/p0zloVjCNWVokJq4rLGkLn80h0I"",
      id: "fS7w-TXinPE",
      contentDetails: {
        duration: "PT1H38M24S", # <--
        dimension: "2d",
        definition: "sd",
        caption: "false",
        licensedContent: true
      } 
    }
  ]
}
```

What is this format, and how to change that the duration in india time??

Comment: You know what, I'm flagging this as spam because: 1. your URL does not contain anything having to do with the string "PT1H38M24S" in the title, and 2. durations do not have a time zone, so changing "that the duration in india time"[SIC] is meaningless. Therefore the only purpose of this "question" must be to promote your video, whatever it may be about.

Comment: Though i would also say that this question is not written very well (what is the intention of the question), I wouldn't mark it as spam, since the url points to a REST-resource at googleapis.com and in the JSON document that lies behind the URL there is a field "duration" with the string "PT1H38M24S". Nevertheless, RAMAR T should definitely improve his question.

Comment: i need to change that  duration: "PT1H38M24S" to 1:38:24

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert youtube Api v3 video duration in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24393230/convert-youtube-api-v3-video-duration-in-php) also see [other duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562195/converting-youtube-data-api-v3-video-duration-format-to-standard-time-in-php).

Comment: Read the funky manual!

Answer (score 3):

It's an [ISO 8601 Date Interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Use PHP's [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php) class

```
$dateInterval = new DateInterval("PT1H38M24S");
echo $dateInterval->h .':' . $dateInterval->i . ':' . $dateInterval->s;
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/S0cRvA)

But 1 hour 38 minutes and 24 seconds is the same duration wherever you are; durations aren't like timezones. India doesn't have its own time durations.

Comment: Working fine ...Thanks for support..